# QueryDict in Django

Tags: python, django

```
from django.http import QueryDict
QueryDict('query=c++')
```

Why the output is, `<QueryDict: {u'query': [u'c  ']}>`

Does querydict remove the + symbol from the string? I am using Python 2.7.17 and Django version 1.10.4.

Answer (score 4):

When you instantiate `QueryDict` class, it invoke [`parse_qs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.parse_qs) to parse the `query_string`(In this case it's `'query=c++'`). See the django `QueryDict` implementation [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/http/request.py#L449).

```
>>> from urllib.parse import parse_qsl
>>> parse_qsl("query=c++")
[('query', 'c  ')]
```

So why the result has space instead of `+`?. Well the answer is within the query string, [the plus sign is reserved as shorthand notation for a space](https://www.w3.org/Addressing/URL/4_URI_Recommentations.html). Therefore, real plus signs must be encoded.

```
>>> from urllib.parse import parse_qsl
>>> parse_qsl("query=c%2B%2B")
[('query', 'c++')]
```

Comment: That works in the shell. But if someone will submit text c++ from Django template. We will receive the only c instead of c++. How to handle that case.

Comment: @starboy_jb Can you update the question with relevant part of template code?

Comment: It is a simple form with one input field, having a method as POST. I am receiving the request in views but I am getting only c instead of c++.

Comment: I have fixed the issue, We can use encodeURIComponent here